# Generating a slideshow under linux

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick

Under Windows, one is able to generate a nice slideshow (crossfading between images, applying the Ken Burns effect on each image) on Windows using (Windows) Movie Maker.

When I create a slideshow using Movie Maker, for 10 images, it takes under 1 minute (without even using the GPU!). I have a machine with one quad-core: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz

On our servers, however, we want to use Debian, so we have been looking for a utility that is able to create such slideshows with the 2 effects (Ken Burns and crossfading).

We found "dvd-slideshow" (http://dvd-slideshow.sourceforge.net/), however this takes 8~9 minutes on our servers (2x4-core: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5640  @ 2.67GHz) with the same set of images.

Dvd-slideshow actually is a wrapper that calls ImageMagick and ffmpeg, so I tried compiling ImageMagick with OpenCL support (since the "convert" commands seem to take the longest), however OpenCL doesn't seem to be used by these kind of image-calculations.

Our goal is to make this as fast as possible, preferably taking < 1 minute for a slideshow with 10 images. The resulting slideshow should be an H.264/MPEG-4-file, since this is compatible with many devices.

Does anyone know a Unix utility to perform this task? Or should I somehow perform this task on a Windows machine?

NB: I also tried Imagination (http://imagination.sourceforge.net/), but this program doesn't allow to have the Ken Burns effect and the crossfading simultaneously, unfortunately

Comment: # aptitude show gwenview # there are some kinds of plugin, check this.